# 2 lists with numbers

Tags: list

I made two lists, one has some numbers from (001 to 999) and the second should have a number which does not exist in the first list. When I get a number to the first list it should disappear from the second list. How could I do it ?

Comment: You can use item adding event of event reciever and check if the number exist in 2nd list.if it does than don't add it or apply whatever logic you want to. your question is not clear though.btw what you want to achieve?

Comment: But not ptrogramicary. From Sharepoint designer or infopath ?

Answer (score 1):

An OOTB solution would be using SP Designer. So you have two lists 1 and 2. Initially 1 is empty and 2 contains all number from 1 to 999, and when a number is added to list 1, it should be automatically deleted from list 2.

I would suggest opening list 1 using SPD and create a new workflow for it, that is being called when a new item is created. Add a condition "if current item:someNumber (or whatever you call it) equals list2:someNumber (here to find the item - below - select someNumber and value = current item:someNumber). It will warn you that it may return multiple results and that the first one found will be returned, which you don't really care unless you have duplicated of numbers in your lists.

Then within the IF condition insert delete item (in list 2, select someNumber and value, currentItem:someNumber).

The simply save and publish the workflow. I'm not sure if this will work 100%, but you can test it by creating a new item in list 1. If it does not work this way, then a "Loop control" workflow could be set up to go through all the items in List 2. But I believe it's not neccesary since there are not duplicates.